# System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: 'The underlying provider failed on Open.' Error?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm working on creating a point-of-sale system using an MVC model in C# and SQL Server, but I seem to be having some kind of issue connecting to the database.

*Web.config:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.8" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.8" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-12.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.7.0" newVersion="5.2.7.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="mythellaneouspc.Cafeteria_POS" 
         connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Cafeteria_POSModel.csdl|res://*/Models.Cafeteria_POSModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.Cafeteria_POSModel.msl;
         provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
         provider connection string=&quot;
         Data Source= Cafeteria_POS; 
         Initial Catalog=Cafeteria_POS; 
         MultipleActiveResultSets=True;
         App=EntityFramework&quot;"
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

The program begins to run and opens a browser window (IIS Express Google Chrome), but the window stays stuck loading while trying to connect to "https://localhost:44378/" and throws these 2 errors.

```
System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: 'The underlying provider failed on Open.'
SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
```

```
System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: 'The underlying provider failed on Open.'
Win32Exception: The network path was not found
```

I have been trying to resolve this for a couple of days now, but I can't seem to find out what's wrong and I could really use some help resolving this.

**[EDIT #1]**

After applying **@DavidBrowne-Microsoft**'s advice, the errors I was having have been fixed, but now it throws "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user." (SqlException (0x80131904)) in Line 26 of FacultyAdmin.cs, which I will attach below.

*Here is the actual text of the Server Error:*

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Login failed for user ''.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user ''.

Source Error:


Line 24:             using (Cafeteria_POSEntities context = new Cafeteria_POSEntities())
Line 25:             {
Line 26:                 return context.Faculties.Include(p => p.Plan).AsNoTracking().ToList();
Line 27:                 //AsNoTracking para no hacer copia en  memoria porque no se hace ningun CRUD 
Line 28:             }

Source File: C:\Users\jpocu\source\repos\POS\POS\POS\Datos\FacultyAdmin.cs    Line: 26

Stack Trace:


[SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user ''.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager) +1524
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +467
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +70
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +940
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +111
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +1567
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +118
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +268
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +315
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +128
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +265
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +133
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch(TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed) +98
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +494
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Execute>b__0() +18
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1 operation) +234
   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open() +324

[EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open.]
   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open() +741
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection(Boolean shouldMonitorTransactions) +166
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction(Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess) +63
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.<>c__DisplayClass41_0.<GetResults>b__0() +227
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1 operation) +234
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption) +357
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__31_0() +30
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext() +39
   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +453
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +73
   POS.Datos.FacultyAdmin.Consultar() in C:\Users\jpocu\source\repos\POS\POS\POS\Datos\FacultyAdmin.cs:26
   POS.Controllers.FacultyController.Index() in C:\Users\jpocu\source\repos\POS\POS\POS\Controllers\FacultyController.cs:19
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +87
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +35
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__9_0(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +77
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__0() +80
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass11_2.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__2() +396
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_6.<BeginInvokeAction>b__4() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +188
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecuteCore>b__152_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +73
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +52
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginProcessRequest>b__20_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +43
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +73
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +431
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +75
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +158
```

*FacultyAdmin.cs*

```
using POS.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace POS.Datos
{
    public class FacultyAdmin
    {
        public void Guardar(Faculty Employee)
        {
            using (Cafeteria_POSEntities context = new Cafeteria_POSEntities())
            {
                context.Faculties.Add(Employee);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<Faculty> Consultar()
        {
            using (Cafeteria_POSEntities context = new Cafeteria_POSEntities())
            {
                return context.Faculties.Include(p => p.Plan).AsNoTracking().ToList();
                //AsNoTracking para no hacer copia en  memoria porque no se hace ningun CRUD 
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**[EDIT #2]**

I'm adding this to explore a possible error in my Connection String/SQL Server configuration.

[Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio "Connect To Server" Dialog Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrcXT.png)
[image: SQL Management Studio Login]

Comment: "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections." means that no server named "Cafeteria_POS" was found or it wasn't listening on the default port of 1433.  This is normal SQL Server connectivity troubleshooting.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft

Oh, okay, thank you! I switched "Data Source= Cafeteria_POS;" to "Data Source = MYTHELLANEOUSPC ;" and those exceptions seem to be fixed, but now it throws the same Error with the Inner Exception "SqlException: Login failed for user." 

Based on some other articles about this error, I tried adding "Integrated Security = false ;", but it doesn't seem to have worked, as it runs and gives a window that tells me there is a "Server Error in '/' Application." ([SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user ''.]) Is there something else I have to add for it to work?

Comment: Its usually the connection string

Comment: @Zee
I figure it has something to do with the connection string, but could you help/tell me what exactly I have to modify/add to the connection string in order to get it working? I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: @Mythellaneous Does your DB need a username and password to connect? or is it just a local DB? Seeing your edit, you probably need a username and password

Comment: @Zee
It's just a local database, and I haven't manually configured any username/password for it. Is there a specific setting I can look for in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio to check if it maybe set up a default username/password combination or something?

Comment: @Mythellaneous Try logging in with SQL Studio. Check the servername, if you can login with the servername in your connection string without any username and password, then your connecting string is correct possibly, Else let us know

Comment: @Zee
The servername is MYTHELLANEOUSPC, but I just noticed it seems to be using Windows Authentication. Could that be the problem? (I'll attach a screenshot of it above.)

Comment: Posted a possible answer below, let me know it that works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `Trusted_Connection=True;` to your connection string

```
<add name="mythellaneouspc.Cafeteria_POS" 
         connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Cafeteria_POSModel.csdl|res://*/Models.Cafeteria_POSModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.Cafeteria_POSModel.msl;
         provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
         provider connection string=&quot;
         Data Source= Cafeteria_POS; 
         Initial Catalog=Cafeteria_POS; 
         Trusted_Connection=True;
         MultipleActiveResultSets=True;
         App=EntityFramework&quot;"
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Comment: It works! Thank you very much for all your help. 

Comment: @Mythellaneous you're very welcome, I've been there :)